# Cannot resolve collation conflict between "Polish_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in CASE operator occurring in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation, sql-server-collation

My query selects data from two databases on the same server.

The server collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

db1 collation is `Polish_CI_AS`

db2 collation was `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` but I changed it to `Polish_CI_AS` using:

```
ALTER DATABASE [db2] COLLATE Polish_CI_AS;
```

Now when I run this script:

```
SELECT name, collation_name FROM sys.databases;
```

I can see that both databases have the same collation `Polish_CI_AS`.

But I still receive below error:

> Cannot resolve collation conflict between "**Polish_CI_AS**" and "**SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS**" in CASE operator occurring in SELECT statement

In the below fragment of query:

```
CASE
    WHEN 1=1 THEN db1.colX
    WHEN 1=1 THEN db2.colY
END AS TEST
```

However, when I add "COLLATE Polish_CI_AS" like:

```
CASE
    WHEN 1=1 THEN db1.colX COLLATE Polish_CI_AS
    WHEN 1=1 THEN db2.colY
END AS TEST
```

or

```
CASE
    WHEN 1=1 THEN db1.colX
    WHEN 1=1 THEN db2.colY COLLATE Polish_CI_AS
END AS TEST
```

then it works.

I also noted that it could be **any** collation, e.g.:

```
CASE
    WHEN 1=1 THEN db1.colX
    WHEN 1=1 THEN db2.colY COLLATE ESTONIAN_100_BIN 
END AS TEST
```

and it still works.

Question:
Why, having the same collation in both databases the query doesn't work but after adding any collation to it it does?

Comment: Database collation change doesnt change collation of the table columns, it needs to be changed manually, which can be a somewhat tedious process because indexes etc depend on the collation

Comment: What's the actual query and why is this `CASE` used? Why `WHEN 1=1 ` ? `COLLATE` will remove the error but prevent the use of any indexes. Even in nvarchar columns, the collation affects the sort order and how indexes are built and searched. It seems this snippet is part of a catch-all query that would be slow even without the collation issues

Comment: I'd assume 1=1 is only to be able to show the snippet, and not relevant to the actual query Panagiotis

Comment: @FAB I'm not so sure. `1=1` is used in simple dynamic SQL code to allow for 0 or more conditions in WHERE. The query would have the same problems even with a meaningful condition though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

db2.colY will still have Polish collation (as shown in `sys.columns`). Changing the database collation doesn't affect that of pre-existing columns.

When you add `COLLATE ESTONIAN_100_BIN` you no longer have conflicting collations of the same precedence but are in the [Explicit Label vs. Implicit Label](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collation-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#explicit-label-vs-implicit-label) case

> the Explicit label ... takes precedence over the Implicit label

Comment: It should be noted that `COLLATE` prevents the use of indexes created using the column's collation. The error goes away but the cost remains

Comment: True but in the case of `CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN db1.colX  WHEN 1=1 THEN db2.colY
END` this isn't going to be anything that an index seek will help with anyway

Comment: This looks like a bad catch-all query (if not combined catch-all and dynamic sql), where the collation is only one of the problems.

Comment: Could be. We have no reason to think that this is in the `WHERE` clause. The question about why adding an explicit collate makes the error go away is still a valid one. If you want to consult with the OP on other issues  than that please do it in the comments in the Q not this answer so I don't get notifications about it

Comment: @MartinSmith I actually think that would use indexes in a `WHERE` as the `CASE` would be elided https://dbfiddle.uk/5CMXIith

Comment: Quite impressive. I'm sure the `1=1` was just for purposes of demoing an expression that gives the error though as it makes no sense and the column alias is `AS TEST` - which implies that it is both used in the `SELECT` clause and just test code (but questions about that need to be directed to the OP not me)